# How can I delete call and sms permissions from google play?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

Because google paly privacy permission change, we remove call and sms permission from out app. But we still get permission warning when we want to release a new version. 
[Google play console capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqMlx.png)

So, how can remove this warning? thx!!

Comment: are you sure your new release apk, not contains any restricted permissions?

Comment: Yeah! I have check it by rebuild apk with apktool.

Comment: Are you sure you don't still have an alpha or beta version with the restricted permissions?

Comment: I have set all apk's status to deactivate that with restricted permissions.

Comment: Same problem here. I've uploaded new apk and only enabled the Default Permission, but the SMS permission continues to be stored and causes the app to be rejected. I don't see how to remove the SMS permission.

Comment: @Mitch I resolve it by submit a version that not a new version just deactivate old version. After this operation, uploaded new version will success. A stupid problem made by Google.

Comment: @shine I have resubmitted it twice, both times with previous versions deactivated.

I also added "permissions": [] to the Android key of my expo object in App.js.

After that, my permissions (view in the 'artifact library') were reduced to only a few, none of them list "SMS".

But still I get this error:
The declared function {Default Phone handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler)} is allowed, but not approved for the specific permissions that are listed in your manifest {READ_SMS}. These excess permissions {READ_SMS} must be removed from your app manifest.

Answer (score 1):

just release the new version and upload

Comment: I got this warning: "Choose at least one core functionality before saving". So, Which one of core functionality should be choose?

Answer (score 0):

I removed SMS permission ,and uploaded a new apk but still rejected. The reason is:

Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality
Connected device companion apps that enable sending and receiving of SMS or calls, Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls. Please remove these permissions from your app.

I don't know what to do

Comment: Did you find any solution about this?